# how to run pig script in background?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Many times I've to run multiple pig script on server. Most of my script takes around 30 mins to complete. I don't want to wait for one script to complete and  then I start another script. So, can I run multiple scripts at once in `grunt` shell simultaneously? or run pig script in background and start another pig script (similar to `nohup`)?

Comment: Have you looked into threading it? I don't know what a pig script is, but you should be able to do it.

Comment: Pig script will do multi threading (map-reduce jobs) for me. I needn't code it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run following command in terminal,

```
nohup pig /home/mypigscript.pig &
```

`mypigscript.pig` will have pig commands.
Found solution after many trial and error :)